# Downgrade .NET framework 4.5 to 4 in Visual Studio 2012 for C++ CLR supported DLL project?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, frameworks

I get this error when linking a Visual C# .NET framework 4.0 supported project as I added a reference of C++ CLR DLL with 4.5 .NET Framework.

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'project' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

As a result, how do I downgrade .NET framework 4.5 to 4.0 in Visual Studio 2012 for this C++ CLR supported DLL project?

I have seen this before which was the cause. For my C++, this link may help out my cause http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772098(v=vs.90).aspx

I just discovered this warning as well:

```
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1578,5): warning MSB3274: The primary reference "X" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".
```

Anyone seen this before? So how I downgrade the C++ DLL?

Thanks

Comment: Dude - what are you talking about?  1) You should be able to configure your project to target pretty much any version of .Net you want, and 2) based on the limited information you gave, I'm not even convinced your build error is necessarily .Net version related.  SUGGESTION: figure out where "project" came from, in your original project.  Post back details.

Comment: I have updated the question but I developed this other C++ DLL

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The C++ IDE doesn't support multi-targeting for .NET projects.  You'll need to edit the .vcxproj by hand.  Close the project if you have it open and open the .vcxproj in a text editor.  Locate this line:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

and modify it to "v4.0".  Open the project again in VS.  Project + Properties, Common Properties, Framework and References.  Select "System" in the list and check the Relative Path property.  It should now point to the 4.0 version.

Do beware of a significant issue and the core reason that the C++ IDE does not support multi-targeting.  There is a problem with the [#using directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yab9swk4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it loads assemblies from the c:\windows\microsoft.net subdirectory.  Which will get it to load a .NET 4.5 assembly instead of the 4.0 assembly that you want when you target 4.0.  The 4.0 reference assemblies are stored in c:\program files\reference assemblies.  This can cause very hard to diagnose runtime problems, the 4.5 assemblies are not that compatible with the 4.0 assemblies.  It is easy enough to avoid #using in your own code but it used in the include/msclr/marshal.h and include/vcclr.h header files.  Caveat emptor if you use these headers.

Comment: Cool - I never knew that.  I use MSVS all the time ... but never for Microsoft's (horrible, IMHO) "CLI/Managed C++.  Good to know - thank you.

Comment: The issue with "include/msclr/marshal.h" and  "include/vcclr.h" also happens if you upgrade a c++/CLR project from 4.5 to 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6 or 4.6.1 in VS2012.

Comment: Same applies when you want to downgrade to plain 4.5 from 4.5.2

Answer (score 2):

I have figured it out. It was the warning but the link specified did fix the problem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772098(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was: in the project properties -> configuration properties -> project defaults. .NET Target framework version - edit to the version you need - in my case 4.6.1