# Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 Managed Test for C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, tdd, mstest

I am having issues using visual studio 2012 managed test project with a c++/cli dll.

The first problem is the warnging MSB3274 could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework "
I cant find any property page in the managed test project to change the targeted framework and if i unload the project and edit the project i cant find the tag to change this.

the next problem is a linker error 
error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000001). 
followed by another linker error
error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

C++/CLI project

Header file:

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace MathLibrary {

    public ref class CustomMathLibrary
    {
    public:
        int Sum(int number1, int number2);
    };
}
```

CPP File:

```
#include "MathLibrary.h"

int MathLibrary::CustomMathLibrary::Sum(int number1, int number2)
{
    return number1 +  number2;
}
```

I then link this project to the managed test project by adding the reference in the properties dialog -> common properties -> Framework and Reference
I then add the header file in the properties dialog -> configuration properties -> C/C++ -> additional include directories

the unit test cpp file

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MathLibrary.h"


using namespace System;
using namespace System::Text;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting;

namespace ImdMathLibraryTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public ref class MathLibTest
    {
    public: 
        [TestMethod]
        void SumTest()
        {
            Assert::AreEqual(1,1);
        }
    };
}
```

thank you to all for any advice to resolve this issue.

Comment: Make sure all the projects you are using in your solution are (where applicable) targeting the same framework number (including tests)

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766957/downgrade-net-framework-4-5-to-4-in-visual-studio-2012-for-c-clr-supported-dl).  You'll need to do a better job documenting the **exact** linker errors.  Start by removing the #include for MathLibrary.h, the class is already imported by adding the reference.